# JDBC DatabaseMetaData returns '0' for COlumn_SIZE in oracle12C

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c, database-metadata

JDBC Database Metadata returns '0' for Column_SIZE in Oracle12C
and we are getting null values only for columns which are having Numeric_Datatypes.

It is perfectly working in Oracle11G or older version of oracle

Here is the piece of code that i am trying to get column_Size  it is returning '0' for only Numeric_Datatype Columns.
Is there any other alternative solutions in order to get column-size ?

```
    dbmd=con.getMetaData();    
    columnRs=dbmd.getColumns(null, null,tableName , null);    
    while(columnRs.next()){

        String header Name=columnRs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");    
        int headerSize=columnRs.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");    
    }
```

Here is Create Table Statement that we are Using

```
CREATE TABLE SUBECTS (
    SUBECT_ID NUMBER, 
    SUBECT_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    UPDATED_DATETIME DATE,  
    HAS_PN VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N', 
    WFL_PHASE_ID NUMBER, 
    SITE_ID NUMBER
)
```

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for the table in question. And what is the exact version of the JDBC driver you are using (you can get that using `java -jar ojdbc7.jar`

Comment: [edit] your question. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: We are using JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.3.0" .

Comment: Actually i tried with ojdbc7.jar but it was still not working  .

Comment: You need to look at `decimal_digits` together with `column_size`. A `number` column will be returned `decimal_digits = -127` and `column_size = 0` . A `number(10,2)` will be returned as `decimal_digits = 2` and `size = 10`. And you should use a 12.x driver for Oracle 12, not a 10.x driver

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver.

Comment: I have tried with updating JDBC  driver. but it was still causing  problem.

Comment: @Mark Can you please provide any link or Url where i can find get alternative solutoin  for this problem

Comment: May be the only solution is to report it as a bug to Oracle; the spec says: _"The COLUMN_SIZE column specifies the column size for the given column. **For numeric data, this is the maximum precision.** For character data, this is the length in characters. For datetime datatypes, this is the length in characters of the String representation (assuming the maximum allowed precision of the fractional seconds component). For binary data, this is the length in bytes. For the ROWID datatype, this is the length in bytes. Null is returned for data types where the column size is not applicable."_